# Xcode 10 storyboard and info.plist git diff is not properly showing

Tags: ios, xcode, git, storyboard, plist

Am facing a strange issue on my `Xcode 10`. Whenever I get conflict on `storyboard` or `plist`, `Xcode` does not showing me the proper way to resolve conflicts. See the screenshot which is an example of `storyboard` case. If I get the conflict on `plist` file, then I can't even open it (`Xcode` saying the file is not proper format). Right now am using `Xcode 9.4` to resolve this issue. Is there a way to fix it in `Xcode 10`. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is happening when you click on commit and check the diff for both of these files, what is the error Xcode is throwing at that point ?

Comment: @MidhunMP commit button will not come on merging , but a merge button come instead, but all conflict has to fix in Xcode then only merge button become clickable. I think its a Xcode bug.

Answer (score 9):

> If I get the conflict on plist file, then I can't even open it (Xcode saying the file is not proper format)

Of course you can’t. Once the conflict has occurred, and the git marker text is inserted into the file, the file is *not* in the proper format — it is no longer a pure XML plist file.

The usual way to see the text within Xcode is to control-click on the storyboard or plist file in the navigator and choose Open As > Source Code.

[image]

What I personally do, however, is to open the file using BBEdit. Either way, you are now looking at the text with the git markers in it.

[image]

Now just edit the text directly, resolving the conflict and eliminating the markers to restore order. Now mark the merge as resolved and commit.

For example, in the above example we have this text:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <string>3</string>
=======
    <string>2</string>
>>>>>>> branch
```

So we would delete the `<<<` line, the `===` line, the `>>>` line, and *one* of the remaining two lines. Now we can mark the conflict as resolved, commit, and proceed.

[image]

It is possible to view and compare the conflicting versions in the Xcode comparison view:

[image]

But I don’t think it brings you any advantage to do so.

Comment: I can open in Xcode 9.4, the issue is only in Xcode 10

Comment: I’m using Xcode 10.2 and I’m just describing what I do.

Comment: And I told you. Just edit the text to resolve. You can do that in Xcode if you like.

Comment: while merging ?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by “while merging”. The merge has stopped due to the conflict. I have explained _in detail_ how to resolve the conflict, entirely within Xcode.

Comment: ok, while merging i got conflict , i have two opttion merge and cancel, , but since i got conflct my merge button is disabled , so i have cancel button , now either i can use cancel button and got to terminal fix the issue , or open old xcode and just selesct the proper side.
now whlie merging on xcode you can/t open by source.
for storyboard do you see the image

Comment: I use BBEdit too. Cake.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Finder`, open that `Info.plist` file in `TextEdit`. You'll see line like this

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <string>322</string>
=======
    <string>402</string>
>>>>>>> branch
```

Remove any of unwanted lines. Open Xcode again, this time it will open normally **without** showing `Xcode saying the file is not proper format.`

> appx: unwanted lines may be
>
> ```
> <<<<<<< HEAD
>     <string>322</string>
> =======
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> =======
>     <string>402</string>
> >>>>>>> branch
> ```