# I can't launch Main.storyboard or LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10

This is what I see when I try to launch main storyboard and I have the same problem with `launchscreen.storyboard`.

When I try to access `main.storyboard` I see XML code instead of the `main.storyboard`.

I get these error messages:

> Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.
>
> Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again. I also get this error "The source control operation failed because the revision could not be found. Make sure a valid revision exists in the repository and try again."

What do they mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191517/storyboard-only-shown-in-xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Git and your storyboard has been merged.
In this situation you have to remove head and tail in xml and launch as Interface Builder.

Comment: I also get this error "The source control operation failed because the revision could not be found. Make sure a valid revision exists in the repository and try again." What do they mean?

Comment: remove <<<<<<<<Head or >>>>>>>>>>>> like lines from xml and open interface builder.like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403366/9697632

Comment: Thanksyou so much appriciate it

Comment: Thanksyou but that not the error I am getting. I get this error when I try to connect my storyboard view controller to my swift code. Yes the class is correct.

Comment: Have you create custom class in Identity Inspector in Storyboard.

Comment: By the way in Launch Screen can not run program